# MATLAB Adaptive Filters

Tags: matlab, adaptive-filters

In the audio domain, I am currently attempting to use MATLAB to distil:

1. $\textrm{signal}$ from $\textrm{noise + signal}$
2. $\textrm{noise}$ from $\textrm{noise + signal}$ 
   using two adaptive filters $\rightarrow$ two results.

I get the first answer quite effectively using:

```
hFDAF1 = adaptfilt.fdaf(AdaptFiltLength,StepSize,Leakage,Delta,Lambda)

[Errors1, Adapt_Out_Audio] = filter(hFDAF1, NoisePlusAudio, Audio)
```

where `NoisePlusAudio` is a microphone in the room, and `Audio` is music playing through speakers in the room.

How do I get the adaptive filter to remove the `Audio` from `NoisePlusAudio`, just leaving the background noise of the room, much like an echo canceller?
The following does not work, it just lets all the sound through.

```
[Errors2, Adapt_Out_Noise] = filter(hFDAF2, Audio, NoisePlusAudio)
```

I'd love to know the answer ....

Comment: I assume your hFDAF2 is similar settings to hFDAF1?

Comment: I use:AdaptFiltLength = 256
StepSize = 0.03
Leakage = 0.9
Delta = 1
Lambda = 0.96

Comment: Would you support this: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94189/matlab Just up vote question with less than 10 votes.

Answer (score 1):

Reason for it might be the continuous adaptation, even in non speech regions. So, you can try Voice Activity Detector (VAD) for knowing the exact regions for adaptation of filter, and processing will be frame wise (20 ms).